# Headphones with noise amplification

Tags: headphones

As there any headphones (open or semi-closed) that can amplify the noise around instead of canceling it? I like to bike with the headphones on, but I need to hear the traffic around. I used earbuds before, but they are easy to lose and not that comfortable.

The best implementation I'd love to have is where I can smoothly control the configuration between full active noise-cancelling and noise-amplification.

They should be also wireless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to hear sounds around you in a proper manner, consider that bone conduction headphones will leave your ears open, while allowing you to enjoy music or other sounds. This type of design also allows your ear's natural direction finding characteristics to function, as very little of the surrounding ear is blocked by bone conduction headphones.

I've used two different types and the wireless ones are certainly the most convenient.

In some states, it is unlawful to have earbuds or earphones, but bone conduction designs do not block the ear and are not unlawful, although it may be necessary to explain to an uninformed uniformed law enforcement officer of the difference.

I've owned two models of AfterShokz and can recommend them for quality sound and functionality.

There's a review of a few models and manufacturers here:
https://www.everydayhearing.com/hearing-technology/articles/bone-conduction-headphones/
that may be useful in your decision process.